# Advantage of use sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have raise one **question** in my mind that *Why we are frequently* **use SQLITE in android**?
there are more option are available but why SQLITE?
option like ::

- **Using Shared Preferences**
- **Using the Internal Storage**
- **Using the External Storage**
- **Using a Network Connection**

Why it is so **easy to use**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have complex data ie huge data which may or may not related to each other. But they want to be displayed in separate way in different views then what will you prefer?

**SQLITE vs Shared Preference**
A SQLite database is meant for huge of entries(eg thousands of records). SQLite database can also be queried and the data retrieval is much more robust. The SQLite database adds immense power to your entries.

**SQLITE vs External Storage**
Wxternal data can be deleted by user at any point of time

**SQLITE vs Internal Storage**
If you wan to query your data, store the data in structured manner you wil prefer SQLite